# Astroquery VizieR UCAC4 full download

Tags: python, astronomy, astropy, astroquery

I would like to have a local (offline) ASCII version of **UCAC4** star catalogue in order to have an isolated work environment.

I am having issues trying to retrieve this specific *full* catalog. Downloading small parts is pretty straightforward using **topcat** *VO->Vizier service* option or even the CdS web interface, but I did not manage full catalogue retrieval.

My best shot was using Python scripting [astroquery](http://astroquery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/vizier/vizier.html) but the following function call does not return nearly enough stars when it should download half the catalogue (Northern part of celestial sphere):

```
ucac4 = v.query_region(coord.SkyCoord(ra=0, dec=45, unit=(u.deg, u.deg), frame='icrs'), 
                       width=90, height=360, catalog= 'I/322A')
```

`width` and `height` seem to refer to *declination*/*ra* in this order (am I wrong with this assumption?)

I also tried to iterate on smaller parts of the sky and it improves the density, but I still seem to have missing objects and cannot figure out why. For instance, I tried to iterate on 0.2° declination steps so I could cross check with this file :
ftp://cdsarc.u-strasbg.fr/pub/cats/I/322A/UCAC4/u4i/zone_stats
but still the `query_region` function does not return the expected amount of stars...

And I also tried [Astrosurf](http://www.astrosurf.com/) links but I cannot just use these files because I want it in an ASCII format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fastest solution : get the [cdsclient](http://vizier.u-strasbg.fr/vizier/doc/cdsclient.html) package. Run the finducac4 program with -whole option, for example :
finducac4 -whole -m 115000000 > myUcac4.dat

Answer (score 3):

To download large data sets, you need to increase the `ROW_LIMIT`.  The default is only 50 because we wanted to limit the load on the vizier servers unless users know what they're doing.

```
from astroquery.vizier import Vizier
Vizier.ROW_LIMIT = 100000000000
```

Comment: Thank you but I had done this already. The thing is I sometime have _more_ stars than expected (some of the stars returned are out of the "box"). try `len(Vizier.query_region(coord.SkyCoord(ra=0, dec=-89.9, unit=(u.deg, u.deg), frame='icrs'), width=0.2*u.deg, height=30*u.deg, catalog='I/322A')[0])` for instance. It returns 10767 objects but if you replace the height by 360 instead of 30, it is only 42... RAs and DECs returned do not seem consistent with the region queried

Comment: OK, I suspect a bug either in astroquery's handling of vizier or in vizier itself.    Consider raising an issue on astroquery.  I'll try to investigate.

Comment: Thx for your help. I tried to perform similar operations on restricted areas directly with the web interface (using box filter at http://vizier.u-strasbg.fr/viz-bin/VizieR-4), and I also had strange results (but I did not manage to apply the exact same requests than with Astropy). I'll write to them in parallel and if no solution is found, raise an issue on astroquery.